# How to represent sinh-1(a) in script?

Tags: javascript, math, trigonometry

I've been skipping math classes, and now I have problems. :)

Can you please explain to me how I should write this expression in Javascript?

[image: sin-1]

Big thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://phpjs.org/functions/asinh:353

That will give you the code for sinh inverse in javascript.

Comment: It's not a perfect implementation of `asinh`, but it will work well for this case because `tan` has some sanitizing effect on the range of possible inputs.

Comment: Just to be clear, "arcsin" is a synonym for "inverse of the sine function".  And sinh is the hyperbolic sine, not the trigonometric function that you are probably familiar with: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HyperbolicSine.html.  And the inverse is: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseHyperbolicSine.html

Comment: Yes, it's not a perfect implementation: the routine on its own will run into trouble for large *negative* arguments. It's easy to fix, though, since the inverse hyperbolic sine is an odd function: `arsinh(-x)=-arsinh(x)`

Comment: @J.M.: That's the biggest issue, but there's also the problem that for sufficiently large values of x, x*x will overflow, and infinity will (incorrectly) be returned.

Comment: @Stephen: If `x` is large, then the asymptotic expression `arsinh(x) ~ ln(2x)-1/(4x^2)` should be a sufficient approximation.

Comment: @J.M.: I agree, but that's not what the implementation in question does, is it?